# How to solve those Qt errors?

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following files part of a `Qt` program:

**checkabder.h**

```
#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_checkabder.h"
class CheckAbder: public QDialog, public Ui::CheckAbder
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
CheckAbder(QWidget *parent=0);
private slots:
void on_lineEdit_textChanged();
};
```

**checkabder.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "checkabder.h"
CheckAbder::CheckAbder(QWidget *parent): QDialog(parent)
{
setupUi(this);
QRegExp regexp("Abder-Rahman");
QValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(regexp, this);
lineEdit->setValidator(validator);
connect(okButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(accept()));
connect(cancelButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(reject()));
}

void CheckAbder::on_lineEdit_textChanged()
{
okButton->setEnabled(lineEdit->hasAcceptableInput());
}
```

When I try to run the application, I get the following errors:

*C:/Users/avbder/Desktop/abder/debug/checkabder.o:-1: In function `CheckAbder':*

*C:\Users\avbder\Desktop\abder/checkabder.cpp:3: error: undefined reference to `vtable for CheckAbder'*

*C:\Users\avbder\Desktop\abder/checkabder.cpp:3: error: undefined reference to `vtable for CheckAbder'*

*C:\Users\avbder\Desktop\abder/checkabder.cpp:3: error: undefined reference to `vtable for CheckAbder'*

*C:\Users\avbder\Desktop\abder/checkabder.cpp:3: error: undefined reference to `vtable for CheckAbder'*

*:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status*

Any ideas on how to solve those issues?

Thanks.

Comment: Style hint: Better add a Ui::CheckAbder* m_ui member instead of inheriting from it.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for the reference to the first virtual method of `CheckAbder(..)`, which it can't find.

Or, it could be just how your class is defined and an issue with your MOC file. See this [blog post on undefined reference to vtable errors](http://lizardo.wordpress.com/2009/04/24/undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-errors-in-qt-derived-classes/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, what should I do in this case?

Comment: Assuming you are using Qt Creator, go to Build > Run qmake, then compile again.

Comment: @Dave. Thanks for your reply. The errors ave gone now, but the functionality of the `connect`s don't work. Why is that?

Comment: @user714961: Sorry, I would need more information. If you are still having problems, post another question, as the problem you are having now seems unrelated.